# Replace C++ preprocessor macro with something that can initialize a struct

Tags: c++

I'm working with WinAPI's `CreateDialogIndirect` function, which has some requirements on the `DLGTEMPLATE` and `DLGTEMPLATEEX` structures pointed to by the second parameter. My code works well, however, I would like to get rid of the `#define` macros.

I created a simplified example to focus on the macros. This is a working program with macros, it can be compiled, and outputs what is expected:

```
#include <iostream>

int wmain()
{
#define TITLE L"Title"
    struct {
        wchar_t title[ sizeof( TITLE ) / sizeof( TITLE[ 0 ] ) ];
        int font_size;
    } s = {
        TITLE,
        12,
    };

    std::wcout
        << L"s.title = "     << s.title     << std::endl
        << L"s.font_size = " << s.font_size << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

In Visual Studio 2022, I see three dots at the `#define` macro, and I can read the following tooltip:

- Macro can be converted to constexpr
- Show potential fixes
- Convert macro to constexpr

I would like to see it converted to something to avoid macros, so I click on it, and the code is changed to this:

```
#include <iostream>

int wmain()
{
constexpr auto TITLE = L"Title";
    struct {
        wchar_t title[ sizeof( TITLE ) / sizeof( TITLE[ 0 ] ) ];
        int font_size;
    } s = {
        TITLE,
        12,
    };

    std::wcout
        << L"s.title = "     << s.title     << std::endl
        << L"s.font_size = " << s.font_size << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

If I hit F7 to compile, I get the following error message:

- example.cpp(10,9): error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'const wchar_t *const ' to 'wchar_t'

I would not like to enter `L"Title"` two times, and I would not like to calculate the length of the string manually. So, what can be a good substitute for the macro, which is capable of both initializing the `struct` and determining the size of the array in the struct?

Comment: What do you want to store in that struct as `title`, an array, a pointer to const, a `std::string` or a `std::string_view`?

Comment: @Bob__ It must be a null-terminated array of `wchar_t`.

Comment: Initializing a raw array with a raw string only works when the initializer expression is the direct string literal (the thing with quote punctuation), and not a variable name or any other expression. You could do something with copying the data into the array after the struct initialization, or maybe "cheat" on the exact types used in a way that will give the byte sequence the API expects.

Comment: You could probably use template deduction guide (see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction). There is an example that deduce an integer from an array so I guess it would be possible to do exactly what you want cleanly.

Comment: You know, there is no actual reason why the variable length struct needs to be stack-allocated. You could write a normal function that takes a vector of dialog item information along with window text class names and all that as strings and returns a vector of bytes that can be casted to a dialog template and call CreateDialogIndirect on that. I don't have time right this second to write an answer like that but if someone else wants to...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A template is a reasonably common replacement for macro usage. Since you don't want to manually calculate the length of the string (I don't blame you), let's make a length (the array length, not the string length) the template parameter. Your anonymous `struct` becomes a likely candidate for being the templated entity, as you do end up with a different type each time you change the length of your title.

The actual conversion to a template is simple enough (given the level of the question) that I won't go over the details here. The nifty part comes when you write a constructor. By using the template parameter in the argument list, the compiler will be able to deduce it. This gives you the ease-of-use you appear to be looking for, albeit at the cost of some additional setup.

***Caveat:** Deducing the template parameter via an argument to the constructor is a C++17 feature. Anyone stuck on C++11 or 14 (hopefully not many of you) can get a similar result by writing a separate function template that constructs and returns a struct. I'll leave that as an exercise.*

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>    // For memcpy


template <size_t N>
struct DlgTemplate {
    wchar_t title[N];
    int font_size;

    // Constructor that will deduce `N`.
    // For those not familiar with this syntax: the incoming title_ is a
    // reference to an array with exactly N elements.
    DlgTemplate(const wchar_t (&title_)[N], int font_size_) :
        font_size(font_size_)
    {
        // Copy the title.
        std::memcpy(title, title_, sizeof(title));
    }

    // Reminder: N is the array length, which includes the null terminator.
    //           The string length is N-1.
};


int main()
{
    // As of C++17, the template argument can be deduced here.
    auto s = DlgTemplate(L"Title", 12);

    std::wcout
        << L"s.title = "     << s.title     << std::endl
        << L"s.font_size = " << s.font_size << std::endl;
}
```

The next consideration is probably how to deal with all the fields that were mercifully left out of the question. One option is to add more parameters to the constructor to handle all of the fields. However, in the interest of readability, I might be inclined to remove `font_size_` as a constructor parameter (remembering to mark the constructor `explicit`) then set each field after construction. The following is what I have in mind for the initialization.

```cpp
    auto s = DlgTemplate(L"Title");
    s.font_size = 12;
    //s.other_field = value;
    // etc.
```

---

There is one important detail to note from the question. The "potential fix" implemented by Visual Studio caused the length information to be lost.

```
constexpr auto TITLE = L"Title";
```

defines `TITLE` to be a pointer (to `const wchar_t`). Its size is fixed, independent of the length of the title. The calculation `sizeof( TITLE ) / sizeof( TITLE[ 0 ] )` does not give the length of the title, and this `TITLE` will not work with the template.

```
constexpr wchar_t TITLE[] = L"Title";
```

defines `TITLE` to be an array, with the length information kept as part of the type. This `TITLE` can be used with the template.

Answer (score 0):

DLGTEMPLATEEX is a special case.  In fact, there is no structures with such a name in the wndows headers.  If you want to use a structure, you must create you own, with custom array sizes.4

Example

```
constexpr TCHAR TITLE[] = _T("Title"); // IMPORTANT! To be 100% sure that's a array,
                                       // declare it explicitely.

struct MyDlgTemplateEx {
  WORD      dlgVer;
  WORD      signature;
  DWORD     helpID;
  DWORD     exStyle;
  DWORD     style;
  WORD      cDlgItems;
  short     x;
  short     y;
  short     cx;
  short     cy;
  TCHAR     menu[1];
  TCHAR     WwindowClass[1];
  TCHAR     title[sizeof(TITLE) / sizeof(TITLE[0]);
  WORD      pointsize;
  WORD      weight;
  BYTE      italic;
  BYTE      charset;
  TCHAR     typeface[1];  // a NULL string.
};
```

The first thing that's obvious it that there are quite a few member variables.  Doing unnamed in-place initialization (as in your example), with no explicit member names can very easily lead to mistakes and bugs.

The most common way of initializing such large structures is explicitely:

```
// ...


MyDlgTemplateEx tmpl = {}; // this declatres and fills structure with zeroes.

// initialize all non-zero members explicitely.
// cutting and pasting the structure declaration and editing around that is fairly fast. 
tmpl.dlgVer = 1;
tmpl.signature = 0xFFFF;   // this is a DLGTEMPLATEEX struct.
tmpl.exStyle = WS_EX_DLGMODALFRAME;
tmpl.style = WS_CAPTION;
tmpl.cDlgItems = 1;
tmpl.x = 10;
tmpl.y = 10;
tmpl.cx = 100;
tmpl.cy = 100;
_tcscpy_s(tmpl.title, TITLE);  // must copy into array that's in structure.
```

Comment: @aschepler I got that.

Comment: If using C++20, you could also do `MyDlgTemplateEx tmpl = { .dlgVer = 1, .signature = 0xFFFF,` ... `}; _tcscpy_s(tmpl.title, TITLE);`. Not a big difference though, since there's no class data involved and the array members need to be copied separately anyway.

Comment: This is a plain c++ qiuestion.

Answer (score 0):

Depends what you really want. One way is to use `std::wstring_view` instead of the array, but this may suit your needs or not.
If it does, it's pretty easy:

```cpp
    struct {
        std::wstring_view title = L"Title";
        int font_size{12};
    } s;
```

Comment: The OP isn’t super clear so I won’t downvote this but the issue is that when using the Win32 API you sometimes have to pass in structs that contain variable length fields packed into the struct. The structs that the OP is looking for need to really have stack allocated fields that are null terminated, I think. I;d have to read the documentation on DIALOGTEMPLATE to see what it wants exactly.